# How and where can I find a good part-time sysadmin?

Tags: untagged

I run a small (tiny for now) business, and I find I need a sysadmin for a couple of hours a month. I'm not good enough at it, and I don't enjoy it so I'm unlikely to ever be so. I'd like to hire outside help. Does anybody have any tips on where to look for, and how to evaluate, sysadmins? If it makes a difference my platform is Java on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used various freelance web sites like [Scriptlance](http://scriptlance.com) and [Get A Freelancer](http://getafreelancer.com) with good success. While those sites mostly focus on programming projects, there are categories for system administration and related tasks.

I've hired several part time junior admins from both of those sites with good results.

Answer (score 5):

If you are near to a college / university I might also suggest that you contact the CS department and see if there is a student that they might be willing to recommend.  The cost is less and you will frequently get as good or better attention than a freelancer.  Explain to the head of the department exactly what you're looking for and give the student a good interview.  It's good for you to make sure you have a picture of exactly what you need and can also help to jump start the career of a young person.

Of course you will not necessarily get the experience you would from a freelancer or consulting firm, so do with this what you will.  But I am a strong advocate of giving young people a chance to get going!

Comment: That's a really good idea, I'll give it a shot as well. Cheers!

Comment: Great!  Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try craigslist

Comment: Only if you're in the US

Answer (score 0):

In most locales, there are usually IT outsourcing specialist companies exactly for companies like yourself.

If you are in London, try RunPcRun (sorry, not trying to advertise, just giving an example that I know of, but they are run by some friends of mine...)